# populate observable array from json

Tags: javascript, json, knockout.js

I have a working test example of what I want to do here: http://jsfiddle.net/2BxVk/6/

Instead of the test months I populate my observable array called allMonths now with (like this)

```
self.tak = ko.observable(100);
self.styckpris = ko.observable(10);
self.grundpris = ko.observable(500);

self.allMonths = ko.observableArray([
new monthData(2013, 1, 412, 142, self),
new monthData(2013, 2, 112, 642, self),              
new monthData(2013, 2, 100, 742, self),
new monthData(2013, 3, 6513, 69, self),
new monthData(2013, 4, 34, 211, self),
new monthData(2013, 5, 123, 435, self),
new monthData(2013, 6, 412, 142, self),
new monthData(2013, 7, 412, 142, self)
]);
```

I want to do a $.getJSON and insert that into my obs array instead.

This is the output of the $.getJSON source if I view it directly from the url:

```
[{"tak":2700,"styckpris":35,"grundpris":20000,"year":2012,"month":2,"ss":784,"ms":576,"count":1360,"price":20000},{"tak":2700,"styckpris":35,"grundpris":20000,"year":2012,"month":3,"ss":977,"ms":636,"count":1613,"price":20000},{"tak":2700,"styckpris":35,"grundpris":20000,"year":2012,"month":4,"ss":1040,"ms":726,"count":1766,"price":20000},{"tak":2700,"styckpris":35,"grundpris":20000,"year":2012,"month":5,"ss":1373,"ms":1013,"count":2386,"price":20000},{"tak":2700,"styckpris":35,"grundpris":20000,"year":2012,"month":6,"ss":856,"ms":612,"count":1468,"price":20000},{"tak":2700,"styckpris":35,"grundpris":20000,"year":2012,"month":7,"ss":594,"ms":299,"count":893,"price":20000},{"tak":2700,"styckpris":35,"grundpris":20000,"year":2012,"month":8,"ss":1261,"ms":826,"count":2087,"price":20000},{"tak":2700,"styckpris":35,"grundpris":20000,"year":2012,"month":9,"ss":1092,"ms":729,"count":1821,"price":20000},{"tak":2700,"styckpris":35,"grundpris":20000,"year":2012,"month":10,"ss":1097,"ms":747,"count":1844,"price":20000},{"tak":2700,"styckpris":35,"grundpris":20000,"year":2012,"month":11,"ss":872,"ms":706,"count":1578,"price":20000},{"tak":2700,"styckpris":35,"grundpris":20000,"year":2012,"month":12,"ss":329,"ms":110,"count":439,"price":20000},{"tak":2700,"styckpris":35,"grundpris":20000,"year":2013,"month":2,"ss":911,"ms":0,"count":911,"price":20000},{"tak":2700,"styckpris":35,"grundpris":20000,"year":2013,"month":3,"ss":1002,"ms":0,"count":1002,"price":20000},{"tak":2700,"styckpris":35,"grundpris":20000,"year":2013,"month":4,"ss":1157,"ms":0,"count":1157,"price":20000},{"tak":2700,"styckpris":35,"grundpris":20000,"year":2013,"month":5,"ss":852,"ms":421,"count":1273,"price":20000}]
```

I have been trying to loop through this array I get from the getJSON and put them in allMonths but I cant figure out the correct syntax. I am not interested in tak, styckpris or grundpris, the 3 first properties, I want year, month, ss & ms

I would like something like:

```
var allMonths = ko.observableArray();
$.getJSON('Simulera/monthData', function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (i, val) {
                allMonths.push( new monthData(val.year, val.month, val.ss, val.ms, self) );
            });
        });
```

but this doesnt work. how can I go through the information json returns and insert them into my observable array as a monthData object type?

Comment: Should work. Could you specify "doesn't work" better?

Comment: well there should be 15 rows, 1 for each month added and displayed but they are not displayed.

Comment: this is what it says inside the console: Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: ReferenceError: allMonths is not defined;
Bindings value: foreach: allMonths

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding `self`.

```
$.each(data, function (i, val) {
    self.allMonths.push( new monthData(val.year, val.month, val.ss, val.ms, self) );
});
```

A working version of your fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2BxVk/7/).